# How to get letter from String by index? C++

Tags: c++, string

Can someone briefly explain how to get a character from index from String in C++.

I need to read the first 3 letters of a String and in java it would be`str.charAt(index)` and I have been searching the internet for a solution for 2h now and still don't understand...

can some one please give me an example.

Comment: `mystring[index];` should do..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::string` provides `operator[]` to access a character by index:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at

Example:

```
const std::string s("hello");
const char c = s[0];
// c is set to ‘h’
```

Comment: Works for English or on a single byte character set. However, if the encoding is UTF-8 or some double byte character set, that only provides the byte at a certain position and not necessarily the character.

Comment: @JosephWillcoxson that’s true, but seems out of scope for this particular question

Comment: @JosephWillcoxson Also, I think that if you use UTF-8 char or bigger, you should use the corresponding string extensions (such as std::u16string or std::u32string), and not std::string directly. I guess that operator[] for those should return the valid information!

Answer (score 1):

**substr()**
It returns a newly constructed string object with its value initialized to a copy of a substring of this object.

**Syntax**
     substr(pos, pos+len)

**Code**

```
std::string str ("Test string"); //string declaration
string sub_string = str.substr(0,3);
```

String index starts from 0.

Comment: Sounds like the asker wants to get a character out of the string, not a string out of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Best place to look would be cpluspluc.com: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/

You may use as earlier mentioned: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator[]/

```
  std::string str ("Test string");
  for (int i=0; i<str.length(); ++i)
  {
    std::cout << str[i];
  }
```

Or better yet: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/at/

```
  std::cout << str.at(i);
```

which also checks for a valid position and throws an out of range exception otherwise.

Alternatively you could use http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/data/
to acces the raw data.

Or if you want to check that your string starts with a specific pattern: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/rfind/

```
  std::string str = "Hey Jude!";
  if (str.rfind("Hey", 0) == 0) {
    // match
  }
```

Comment: Re: "better yet": that's not better. You already know that `i` is within the string, because you wrote it that way. There's no need for the redundant check that `str.at(i)` does.

Comment: true :) poor example.

Answer (score -1):

Another option to obtain a single character is to use the [std::string::at()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/at) member function. To obtain a substring of a certain length, use the [std::string::substr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) member function.